# Indirect as the column index number when using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can you use INDIRECT as the `Column Index Number` when using VLOOKUP

I get a #ref! error when I use `=VLOOKUP(B4,H$1:K$6,INDIRECT(C$3),0)`

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `INDIRECT` at all here?

Comment: @AlexisOlson It doesn't have to be `INDIRECT` but i do need it to be a number from a cell as the `Column Index Number`

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply put C3 ?

Comment: if that isn't working the cell is probably formatted as text, put `C3-0` or `C3*1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned you don't need indirect. Simply use the cell reference direct and wrap in an IFERROR to handle if not found.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,H$1:K$6,C$3,0),"")
```

If you did, for no advantage I can see, want to use indirect then it must be a string as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,H$1:K$6,INDIRECT("C3"),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put quotes around the referenced cell -- so it looks like INDIRECT("C3"). That way it recognizes the input as text.

Comment: This seems redundant of the accepted answer from 2018. The text you deleted while editing your post might have been helpful add-on information, albeit somewhat impertinent to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).